# How to combine date and time into a timestamp in db2?

Tags: sql, date, time, db2, timestamp

In a `db2` database I have a `DATE` column and a `TIME` column, how can you combine these into a single `TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`timestamp` function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000859.html) can be called with two arguments, one of which is date and one of which is time:

```
select timestamp(date_col,time_col) from your_table
```

Comment: Fantastic, that is super handy :)

Answer (score 2):

As per [this thread](http://www.iprodeveloper.com/forums/aft/52557), the `[TIMESTAMP][2]` function can accept 2 parameters, so you can simply pass it the `DATE` and `TIME` components and it constructs the `TIMESTAMP` for you.

```
SELECT MyDate, 
       MyTime, 
       TIMESTAMP(MyDate, MyTime) AS MyTimestamp 
FROM MyTable
```